# Comparing Strings using a buffer

Tags: java, string, compare, buffer

I have a problem when comparing Strings. Let's say for example I have a buffer for a string that holds 1024 bits. If I fill that buffer up with the String "Hello", then the buffer would contain "Hello" + the remaining amount of bytes. If I create another String assigned "Hello", without any pre-assigned buffer. The two would never be equal because of this buffer.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
String a = someInputStream.read(buffer); // A will contain "Hello" + rest of bytes.
String b = "Hello"; // Same string but with no buffer
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // Would print false
```

Is there any way that I could compare these two strings without considering the buffer?

Comment: Usually you use the `length` of actually read bytes... also, you need to tell us why `someInputStream.read(buffer);` can't use that `length` to return the correct `String`. Plus, what about multiple block(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inputStream.read(buffer) returning a int not an String. You can compare as follows.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
inputStream.read(buffer); // A will contain "Hello" + rest of bytes.
String b = "Hello"; // Same string but with no buffer
System.out.println(new String(buffer).trim().equals(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple: strings in java are unlike c-strings not ended by a 0. So the `String` created from the buffer will have length 1024 and a lot of 0s at the end. Apart from that `inputStream.read(buffer)` will return an `int` indicating how many bytes were actually read, not a `String` containing the buffer.